# Showing table rows based on user's actions

Tags: javascript

I would like to show some parts of my table only if user has chosen certain radio button, for example:

```
if (radiobutton value == 'address' {
   //show addressrows;
}
else {
   //show other
}
```

I'm new to Javascript so I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to hook the `change` or `click` event of the radio button element. Then you'll want to access the table row elements and set their `display` style property to "none" (hide) or "" (show).

Some notes:

- To access an element, you might use [`document.getElementById`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-getElBId), or [`getElementsByTagName`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-A6C9094), or use those to find some base element (the table, perhaps) and navigate via [`childNodes`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-1451460987) and other such properties of the [`Node`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-1950641247) and [`Element`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-745549614) interfaces.
- To attach an event handlers, you probably want [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) ([`attachEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on IE). (Although you *can* just use `element.onclick = function() { ... };` and similar, that's a very limited approach.)

Here are some examples, first using the DOM methods above directly, then looking at how libraries can help you out.

**Example**:

HTML:

```
<body>
<label><input type='radio' name='rdoOptions' value='on' checked>On</label>
<label><input type='radio' name='rdoOptions' value='off'>Off</label>
<table id='theTable'>
  <tbody>
    <tr class='foo'>
      <td>This cell is in a 'foo' row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is not</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is not</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='foo'>
      <td>This cell is in another 'foo' row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='foo'>
      <td>This cell is in a 'foo' row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>This is not</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script>(...the code below...)</script>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
// This code is inserted where you see %code% in the
// HTML panel on the right. Note that that's just before
// the closing body tag -- that's important, because our
// `init` function assumes the radio buttons already exist
// in the DOM, so this code must be *after* them in the
// markup.
(function() {

    init();

    function init()
    {
        var list, index, elm;

        // Find the buttons and attach handlers to them
        list = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (index = 0; index < list.length; ++index) {
            elm = list[index];
            if (elm.type === 'radio' && elm.name === 'rdoOptions') {
                hookEvent(elm, 'click', radioClickHandler);
            }
        }
    }

    function radioClickHandler(event) {
        var showFlag;

        // On IE, the event isn't passed as an argument, it's a global
        // property of `window`, so we handle that with the curiously-
        // powerful || operator. More about ||:
        // http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html
        event = event || window.event;

        // In an event handler, `this` will refer to the element the
        // handler is attached to

        // Show if the button clicked was "on", hide otherwise
        showOrHideRows(this.value === 'on');
    }

    function showOrHideRows(showFlag) {
        var displayValue, table, rows, index, row;

        // Determine our display value
        displayValue = showFlag ? "" : "none";

        // Get the table, then find all the rows in it
        table = document.getElementById('theTable');
        rows  = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');

        // Loop through them, showing or hiding
        for (index = 0; index < rows.length; ++index) {
            // Get this row
            row = rows[index];

            // Is it a 'foo' row?
            // Note: This check only works if 'foo' is the ONLY class
            // on the row, which isn't very realistic
            if (row.className === 'foo') {
                // Yes, show or hide it by assigning our display value
                row.style.display = displayValue;
            }
        }
    }

    function hookEvent(element, eventName, handler) {
        if (element.addEventListener) {
            element.addEventListener(eventName, handler, false);
        }
        else if (element.attachEvent) {
            element.attachEvent("on" + eventName, handler);
        }
        else {
            element["on" + eventName] = handler;
        }
    }
})();
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/icixu6)

---

**Off-topic**: This stuff can be made a **lot** easier using a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). They abstract away a lot of browser differences and provide a lot of additional functionality.

For instance, here's the JavaScript for the above using JQuery:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  // Find our radio buttons and hook up the handler
  $('input[type=radio][name=rdoOptions]').click(handleRadioClick);

  // Our radio button click handler
  function handleRadioClick(event) {
    // Show if the button clicked was "on", hide otherwise
    showOrHideRows(this.value === 'on');
  }

  // Show or hide rows
  function showOrHideRows(showFlag) {
    var rows = $("#theTable tr.foo");
    if (showFlag) {
      rows.show();
    }
    else {
      rows.hide();
    }
  }

});
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/icixu6/2)

...and even that is fairly verbose because I wanted to be clear what I was doing. It can get downright condensed:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  $('input[type=radio][name=rdoOptions][value=on]').click(function() {
    $("#theTable tr.foo").show();
  });
  $('input[type=radio][name=rdoOptions][value=off]').click(function() {
    $("#theTable tr.foo").hide();
  });

});
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/icixu6/3)

...even cryptic:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  $('input[type=radio][name=rdoOptions]').click(function() {
    $("#theTable tr.foo")[this.value === 'on' ? 'show' : 'hide']();
  });

});
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/icixu6/4)

(That works because you can access JavaScript properties using `['name']`, and functions are proeprties, and so `obj.show()` and `obj['show']()` mean the same thing. So it uses a ternary operator [`condition ? trueValue : falseValue`] to select either "show" or "hide" as the name of the function to call, then call it. But that's really cryptic.)

Comment: Kudos for adding the example! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the id attribute of your table rows and hide them like this:

```
<table>
   <tr id="address"></tr>
   <tr id="other"></tr>
</table>

<script>
if (radiobutton.value == 'address' {
    document.getElementById("address").style.display = ""; 
    document.getElementById("other").style.display = "none";
}
else {
    document.getElementById("address").style.display = "none"; //hide the row
    document.getElementById("other").style.display = ""; //show the row
}         
</script>
```

Comment: But how about the conditional clause about radiobutton values?

Comment: Modified my response to include the if statement.

Comment: onclick="placerow.style.display='show()' This is not working, but could it?

Comment: It is not supposed to work. Try wrapping everything in a separate function and call it like this: onclick="toggle()"